# Why does py.test runs modules doctests backwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pytest, doctest

If I have these two files:

`first_module.py`

```
def add(a, b):
    """
    >>> add(1, 2) # should this not fail first?
    3
    """
    return a - b # (because here's the mistake)
```

`second_module.py`

```
from first_module import *

def anti_add(a, b):
    """
    >>> anti_add(1, 2) # why does this fail first?
    -3
    """
    return -add(a, b)
```

And I run:

```
py.test --doctest-modules -x second_module.py
```

I get:

```
========================================== FAILURES ===========================================
__________________________________ [doctest] second_module.anti_add __________________________________
005 
006     >>> anti_add(1, 2) # why does this fail first?
Expected:
    -3
Got:
    1

.../second_module.py:6: DocTestFailure
```

But I would actually expect the first test to fail first, because `add` is needed to be functional for `anti_add` to work.
I sometimes get confused because `anti_add` test fails because of an error in `add`, but I read no failure in `add` so I assume that it works okay.

How do I make `py.test` run tests in modules the other way round?

Comment: Add `doctest.testmod()` to the 1st module?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Would it mean that I'd need to add this line in every file then in my modules hierarchy to reverse the whole procedure?

Comment: Does that work? I don't know if that is the best way...

Comment: @Chris_Rands Well.. I cannot get it working. Where would you add this line? Personally, I find it quite artefactual having to add it to every file. I hope there's another way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly pytest do not have such a feature. It can only run tests for selected files or folders.

This command:

```
pytest --doctest-modules -x second_module.py
```

means that pytest will scan docstrings in file second_module.py and run tests for them (-x mean stop  for first fail). It does not look for docstrings in required modules.

If you want test all modules you can simply use:

```
pytest --doctest-modules
```

or experiment with option --doctest-glob.

Comment: Okay, so you mean it would be my responsibility to test my modules in correct order? :) With `pytest --doctest-modules first_module.py second_module.py` *etc.*?